# call to Partial View in a blade that is already extending the layout: Laravel 5.2.37

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have repeated Html that has two buttons. Clicking on any of the button reload the page. So far I am doing this in almost 6 controllers and each of their blades has these two buttons and clicking on button has repeated code in their controller.

IN .NET, we can use Partial View that renders the Html at run time which we think will be repeated in many views.

I meant, in a particular blade, we can extend the layout. So far it is fine. Now, how can we call a view in blade that is already extending a layout?

In .NET we write the code like below

```
@Html.Partial("PartialViewExample")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include one blade file into another, just use `@include`

```
@include('path.after.view.folder')
```

[Documentation for Blade control structures](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#control-structures)

Comment: Can I pass route parameters in the above php code? I want to execute Controller's action method at the time of html rendering from server side.

Comment: No, but it will inherit everything from the parent blades, and you can also use any Laravel functions within it.

Comment: You can also pass parameters to the include like so `@include('path.to.file', $data)`

Comment: @AfikDeri: Can you please make an answer with explaination like how to retrieve the passed value in blade?